# Using this keyword to access function pointers in C++

Tags: c++

Shown below is a working code. But I want to use "this" keyword to call my function pointers inside my implementation (e.g inside the constructor implementation). Please help me to come up with a solution.

My system is
g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)

**Working Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class TestClass{
public:
    typedef int (TestClass::*FunctionPtr)(int);
    map <string, FunctionPtr> mFnPtrMap;

    int Function1( int nAdd ) { return nAdd + 1; }
    int Function2( int nAdd ) { return nAdd + 2; }

    TestClass() {
        mFnPtrMap.insert( make_pair( "Function1", &TestClass::Function1) );
        mFnPtrMap.insert( make_pair( "Function2", &TestClass::Function2) );
    }

    int CallFunction( const string & s, int n ) {
        FunctionPtr fp = mFnPtrMap[s];
        return (this->*fp)(n);
    }
};

int main() {
    TestClass ts;
    cout << ts.CallFunction( "Function1", 0 ) << endl;
    cout << ts.CallFunction( "Function2", 0 ) << endl;
}
```

**What I want to do is:**

My expectation is to change it into something like this (use 'this->' instead of 'TestClass::')

```
 mFnPtrMap.insert( make_pair( "Function1", &this->Function1) );
```

It gives me a compiler error. It even suggests me to use TestClass:: name resolution.

> "ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form
>   a pointer to member function.  Say &TestClass::Function1"

Does that mean it's not possible? If someone could give me an explanation also, it would help me to understand the theory underneath. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to use this instead of the class name? What advantage do you see arising out of it?

Comment: If it's just about avoid the explicit use of the class name, I suggest using `decltype` and `std::remove_pointer` to reconstruct it from `this`. As in c++11 you can use the following piece of code `std::remove_pointer<decltype(this)>::type` as a drop-in replacement for the explicit class name

Comment: It's not to gain an advantage. I want to give it a non-static look in my code just to adapt to local coding standards we follow.

Comment: I suggest looking at changing the coding standards instead of your code.   Or perhaps you just don't understand the coding standards.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess for a reason behind this part of the C++ standard, it's that the types of expressions are hardly equivalent. Just compare how you would need to call the function if in a single expression without the function call as some sort of indirection:

```
 (this->*TestClass::function)(); // Binding the member pointer to an instance
```

Here we bind the member pointer to an instance with the `->*` operator which fills the implicit `T*` argument each member function has, the one named `this`. Some other language ask you to provide it explicitely, for example Python but I'm sidetracking a bit.

```
 this->function();
```

Here the subexpression `this->function` already bound the parameter of `this` to the local `this` object which mean that this does in fact in no way refer to a function. Consequently, you can not take an address of it.

You could argue that this should be allowed as part of the standard but consider the fact that you can shadow function declarations in child classes. That means that introducing a second expression for expressing `&TestClass::function` would only introduce confusion. In the current form it is very clear which `function` we are referring to whereas in a `this->function` form it would not be, especially newcomers might assume that this is completely dynamic as `this` is not a static object. It would also not be interely unreasonable to assume that there in fact is a difference between the expressions.

In the mean time, I can only offer a way to remove the explicit referal to the class by some type level computations:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T>
using This = typename std::remove_const<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::type;

TestClass::TestClass() {
    mFnPtrMap.insert( make_pair( "Function1", &This<decltype(this)>::Function1) );
    mFnPtrMap.insert( make_pair( "Function2", &This<decltype(this)>::Function2) );
}
```

Comment: <type_traits> is supported by C++11 onwards only. Anyway +1 for your effort and explanation.

Comment: @SajithP I'm sorry, I did not find a way without using the c++11 feature `decltype`.